# Azure web/worker role read configuration settings

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

What is the best way/recommended way to read settings from a worker/web role?

Is it:

`CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ConnectionString")`  (this I'm using)

or

`RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("ConnectionString")`

Although both work fine ...

[image]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From the documentation for [`CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudconfigurationmanager.getsetting.aspx):

> The GetSetting method reads the configuration setting value from the
>   appropriate configuration store. If the application is running as a
>   .NET Web application, the GetSetting method will return the setting
>   value from the Web.config or app.config file. If the application is
>   running in Windows Azure Cloud Service or in a Windows Azure Website,
>   the GetSetting will return the setting value from the
>   ServiceConfiguration.cscfg.

From above, it is clear that the function `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting` reads either from service configuration (`ServiceConfiguration.cscfg`) file or application configuration file (`App.config`/`Web.config`) depending on where the application is running.

[`RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.getconfigurationsettingvalue.aspx) will **only** read from the service configuration file.

If your application component is used in both cloud and non-cloud applications, use `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting` so that you don't have to make any changes in the code. If your component would run only in the cloud, then I guess you could use either one.

Comment: I would recommend to use `CloudConfigurationManager` and avoid using the `RoleEnviroment`. RE is inside of a not-nuget-friendly library `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime` :(

Comment: First link is 404 (non friendly url is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt634649.aspx)