# need to use appsettings in azure service

Tags: azure

I am working on a web application which is for some unknown reason published to azure services instead to the azure website.  I have some appsettings, which I need.  I see that there is no place in the configure settings in the Azure Services to set up appsettings.  Is there another way I can setup appsettings for this web application

Answer (score 3):

In cloud services, you can still make use of `appSettings` section in your `web.config`. It works the same way as your regular web application. Only difference is that you cannot manually edit that section because web.config gets bundled in the package. So anytime you need to make change to a setting in web.config, you would need to redeploy the package.

Other alternative (and the recommended one) is to make use `Service Configuration` file. You can define your application settings in that file.

Comment: So I am using CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting but I do not get the value.

Comment: That's odd. This should have read the value from Service Config file if the code is running as a web role otherwise from web.config (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643383/azure-web-worker-role-read-configuration-settings). Can you share relevant config files (remove any sensitive information of course)?