# Error on azure web app deployment

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cloud-services, azure-web-app-service, blobstorage

I am new in azure application development. As per the requirements given to me, I had developed an application on azure and successfully deployed it on azure cloud.Blob storage was also being used in that application. Everything was working fine.

When I was deploying it on cloud then that time I was not very much aware about azure deployment so I had deployed it as a cloud service. It worked fine but the only issue was about slow loading at the very first time. Then after doing lot of research I found some solutions so I have deployed it as web app then the slow loading problem was resolved. But with web app deployment, I am facing another problem with a single page which is using blob storage. Below is the error I am getting when opening that specific page :

[image]

Below is the code which I had written :

```
public List<string> ListContainer()
        {
            List<string> blobs = new List<string>();

            if (!Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable) return null;

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("FileStorageAccount"));
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            IEnumerable<CloudBlobContainer> containers = blobClient.ListContainers();

            foreach (CloudBlobContainer item in containers)
            {
                foreach (IListBlobItem blob in item.ListBlobs())
                {
                    blobs.Add(string.Format("{0}", blob.Uri));
                }
            }

            return blobs;
        }
```

It is working fine when running on visual studio but on deployment If I am going with cloud service deployment then I am not getting this specific error. Other pages are working fine with web deployment. The page which causing an error uses blob storage.

I had done lot of research but no luck. Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have not defined the "FileStorageAccount" Setting in the CSCFG file.  Try using the [CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt634649.aspx) method.  It will read configuration values from the web.config or service configuration file.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/19643516/5382426.