# Azure web app ConfigurationManager.AppSettings is null

Tags: azure

I try to learn a little bit Azure web app stuff but...

I add an application setting to the deployment slot and try to read it via ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TEST"] but it is empty.

[Azure portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wNfz.jpg)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TEST"];
            Button1.Text = text;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Configuration Manager only gives you access to your local config file, to get access to the Azure configuration settings you need to use either the `CloudConfigurationManager` class or the `RoleEnvironment` class.

More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643383/azure-web-worker-role-read-configuration-settings).